# Change the border of a rectangle on hover in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a rectangle :

```
PlayButton = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(324, 380, 354, 35))
```

and I want to make the border of the rectangle change colour say to red whenever the user hovered over the rectangle

```
# Checks if the rectangle is hovered over 
if PlayButton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            print ('mouse is over newGameButton')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a state variable when the the muose hover:

```py
hover = PlayButton.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

Draw an additional [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) where the `width` parameter is set:

e.g. red border with a thickness of 3

```py
if hover:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(324, 380, 354, 35), 3)
```